$n$-th moment of the generalized pareto distribution
I need urgent help in calculating the $n$-th moment of the generalized pareto distribution. This distribution is characterized by a shape paramter $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$ und scale parameter $\sigma>0$. The case $\xi\ge0$ is clear to me. For $\xi<0$ the density of the generalized pareto distribution is given by $$f(x)=1_{[0,-\sigma/\xi)}(x)\frac{1}{\sigma}\left(1+\xi\frac{x}{\sigma}\right)^{-(1+\xi)/\xi}.$$This is, what I already have: $$E[X^n]=\dots=\frac{\sigma^n}{\xi^{n+1}}(-1)^{n-1}\int_0^1x^n(1-x)^{-1/\xi-1}\,dx=\frac{\sigma^n}{\xi^{n+1}}(-1)^{n-1}B(n+1,-1/\xi),$$ where $B$ is the beta function. How do I proceed? What properties of beta and gamma function do I use?

Your expression for the $n^{\rm th}$ moment is correct, and using the definition of the beta function in terms of gamma functions, may also be written
$$\operatorname{E}[X^n] = \left(-\frac{\sigma}{\xi}\right)^n \frac{n! \,\Gamma(1 - \frac{1}{\xi})}{\Gamma(n+1-\frac{1}{\xi})}. \tag{1}$$
This illustrates that when $\xi = 1/m$ for some negative integer $m$, there is an elementary closed form for the moments; e.g., when $\xi = -1/2$ we have
$$\operatorname{E}[X^n] = \frac{2^{n+1} \sigma^n}{(n+1)(n+2)}.$$

Let $g_n$ denote the expression you cite from your textbook:
$$g_n(\sigma,\xi) = \frac{\sigma^n}{\xi^{n+1}} \frac{n! \, \Gamma(1/\xi - n)}{\Gamma(1+1/\xi)}, \tag{2}$$
and consider the ratio
$$r_n(\xi) = \frac{\operatorname{E}[X^n]}{g_n(\sigma,\xi)} = \frac{(-1)^n \xi \Gamma(1 + 1/\xi) \Gamma(1 - 1/\xi)}{\Gamma(1/\xi - n) \Gamma(n+1-1/\xi)}, \tag{3}$$ which does not depend on $\sigma$.  Then recall Euler's reflection formula
$$\Gamma(1-z)\Gamma(z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z}, \quad z \ne \mathbb Z, \tag{4}$$
and the fundamental property $\Gamma(z+1) = z \Gamma(z)$.  Hence for any integer $n$,
$$\begin{align}
\Gamma(n+1-z)\Gamma(z-n) &= \Gamma(1-(z-n))\Gamma(z-n) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi(z-n)} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z \cos n \pi - \sin n \pi \cos \pi z} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z \cos n \pi} \\
&= \frac{(-1)^n \pi}{\sin \pi z} \\
&= (-1)^n \Gamma(1-z)\Gamma(z). \tag{5}
\end{align}$$
Using this result with the choice $z = 1/\xi$, provided $1/\xi$ is not an integer, $(3)$ becomes $$r_n(\xi) = \frac{\xi \Gamma(1 + 1/\xi)}{\Gamma(1/\xi)}.$$
But since $\Gamma(1 + 1/\xi) = \frac{1}{\xi} \Gamma(1/\xi)$, we immediately have $r_n(\xi) = 1$, which establishes that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent whenever $1/\xi$ is not an integer.  Of course, we would prefer to use $(1)$ when $\xi < 0$, since it is well-defined for all negative reals, whereas $(2)$ is indeterminate whenever $\xi \in \{\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n-1}, \frac{1}{n-2}, \ldots\}$.

My textbook states, that $E[X^n]=\sigma^n/\xi^{n+1}\cdot\left(n!\Gamma(1/\xi-n)\right)/\Gamma(1+1/\xi)$ for all $\xi<1/n$. I am therefore trying to prove this expression. Does this formula really hold for all $\xi<0$?. For example, if we take $\xi=-1/2$, we would get $1+1/\xi=-1$. Are negative inputs for $\Gamma$ allowed?

@Ilja See amended answer.  For future reference, please provide such details in the body of your question so as to avoid potential confusion regarding the nature of your question.
